# How can i send an element to the background

Tags: css, html

I have a problem. On my webpage I have implemented a clock which has absolute position, and is interfering with my dropdown menu.

My **html code** for the clock is as follows, where **txt** is a parameter i get from my JavaScript:

```
<time>
     <div id="txt"></div>
</time>
```

and my **css code** is like this:

```
time{
     border: 2px dashed red;
     font-size: 80px;
     font-family: circle;
     position: absolute;
     top: 15px;
     left: 43%;
     }
```

Because the clock is in front of my menu I cannot accesss nested unnumbered lists. What can I do to send my clock to the background?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set the z-index to be lower than the menus z-index.

```
time {
    z-index: 900;
}

menu {
    z-index: 950;
}
```

Comment: How can i make my mouse completely ignore the clock? It the moment i can still mark it and i dont like that.

Comment: @71GA - A good question.  I don't have a specific answer for you. I suggest ask it as a new question on stack overflow.

Comment: z-index: -9; -ve values are also supported. I think the -ve z value will push the item/div back and +ve value brings it forward

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri could you be more specific? z-index can be tricky because of the nesting HTML tags.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Setting the time tag to be lower in z-index to other elements is a good solution. However you can also send the time tag to back. using z-index : -1 (given you have only one time element).

```
time {
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the CSS property [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index).

Give your `time` element a lower z-index than whatever it is you're wanting to put it behind.
Without seeing your code it's a little hard to be exact.